# need output as largest number is :the value we are giving in prompt

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

need to alert value of greatest number value in alert box along with "largest number is :"

```
var a=prompt(" first enter the number"),b=prompt("enter the second number");
if(a>b)
{
    alert("largest number is :")
}
else{
    alert("largest number is :")
}
```

Comment: Dealing with numbers I would suggest you use `parseInt()` and as for the output all you need to do is add `:"+a);` and `:"+b);` Reason for suggesting you use `parseInt()` in Prompt 1 input a number... 3 for example, now for prompt two input text.... the alert is now returning a false reading.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the correct number to your alert

```js
var a=prompt(" first enter the number"),b=prompt("enter the second number");
if(a>b)
{
    alert("largest number is :" + a);
}
else{
    alert("largest number is :" + b);
}
```

Comment: Since you have submitted an answer I would highly recommend you include `parseInt()`, prompt 1 input a number `3` - promp 2 `hello World` - alert will return `largest number is : Hello world'` Which hello world isn't a number so this is returning a false reading so you will also want to check for the prompts returning `NaN`

Comment: @NewToJS OP's question was about string concatenation. I solved this problem. `parseInt()` is in fact a good idea but you don't know the goal of OP. He is asking for a number - not an integer. You can't say that he has to use `parseInt()`

Comment: I didn't say anyone **Has to** I  said I would recommend it since the prompt is asking for a number.... an integer it would be better to parse the results as a number/integer, would it not? This can change the result of the if condition from being true to false. Yes, this does answer the OP's question but it doesn't really cover the other problems which wouldn't qualify as a good solution. If anything it's just contributing towards or ignore further problems.